# svn checkout issue (download process interrupted, can I continue?)

Tags: svn

I've tried to download some files from Subversion repository,

But the download process has been interrupted by some network problem.

Can I continue the download process?

`svn update` function is for that? Or should I start from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

`svn update` will finish the checkout

Answer (score 0):

Svn Update will Start from where it was stop... still I would suggest you that you will go through documentation of Svn [svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

[svn update command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)

Answer (score 0):

SVN has `Checkout` to create a local version of a repository and `Update` will then pull any `Commit` changes to the server repository onto the local copy ensuring that none of the local changes are overwritten by either `Merging` or raising a `Conflict`.

SVN can also `Export` a repository which simply obtains the files and does not 'hook' the destination folder into the server repository.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a command line based svn? After a failed download I would suggest to first execute a `svn cleanup` in order to clean your working copy of any locks or inestable svn information and later execute `svn update`.

The purpose of `svn update` is to update you revision with the specified version (the latest by default) from the repository.

For further reference I would recommend this online book:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

An example (and deeper description) of how to perform the initial `svn checkout`, which I assume is what failed to you, can be found in this section:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.initial.html

And the description of the work cycle and the basics of how ot use the svn update command can be found here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html

I hope it helps.